# How to make a UIImageView display fullscreen (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell. When the image is tapped I want the image to display full screen. What do I need to add to my code?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "makeLarger")
    cell.itemImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)


    return cell
}


func makeLarger(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {



}
```

Comment: you don't have any code now where is the data you passing in my friend

Comment: I created a tap gesture in cellForRowAtIndexPath and then created the action function makeLarger. Can you tell me where I am wrong? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a customTableviewCell in which you have an ImageView IBOutlet, Then in your viewDidLoad() append your array of data.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    var images = self.data[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageview.image = UIImage(named: images)
    cell.imageview.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imageview.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    var tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tap"))
    tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)

    return cell
}

func tap(){

 print("tap")
// then you should pass the single image to the DestinationViewController 
}
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with this one because using this way you cannot choose what image to show if you tap one in a cell

Answer (score 1):

This code makes your imageView full screen:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
```

It looks something like this(the image became full-screen after I tapped the button)
[image: the gif]